# Using session scoped Spring bean with DWR

Tags: spring, dwr

Spring: 2.5.6.SEC01

DWR: 2.0.5

I would like to use a session scoped bean from DWR. It works fine, when I configure the bean to be a singleton. I read this tutor:
(http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/server/integration/spring.html)
and modified my applicationContext.xml, but it is still wrong somewhere.

My applicationContext.xml:

http://pastebin.com/m8d57f18

It ork well, but when I use an AJAX function, I get this exception:

> 11:31:09,593 INFO  [DefaultRemoter]
>   Exec: DBTestAjaxFunc.testJNDI()
>   11:31:09,609 WARN  [DefaultRemoter]
>   Method execution failed: 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'scopedTarget.dbtestajax': Scope
>   'session' is not active for the
>   current thread; consider defining a
>   scoped proxy for this bean if you
>   intend to refer to it from a
>   singleton; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: No
>   thread-bound request found: Are you
>   referring to request attributes
>   outside of an actual web request, or
>   processing a request outside of the
>   originally receiving thread? If you
>   are actually operating within a web
>   request and still receive this
>   message, your code is probably running
>   outside of
>   DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet:
>   In this case, use
>   RequestContextListener or
>   RequestContextFilter to expose the
>   current request.

It seems, that the aop proxy wasn't created, but I don't know why.

Libs in the classpath:

- aspectjrt.jar
- aspectjweaver.jar
- cglib-nodep-2.2.jar
- dwr.jar
- spring.jar
- spring-aop.jar
- spring-dwr-2.0.xsd
- spring-web.jar
- spring-webmvc.jar

Any idea? (Thanks!)

Comment: Are you going through a Spring `DispatcherServlet` in `web.xml`?

Comment: yes, when I dont use any ajax feature in the page, it works, like a spring form with controller etc.

Comment: No, I mean is the DWR request passing through the `DispatcherServlet`, or is it going directly to DWR?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039522/getting-a-no-thread-bound-request-found-error-from-spring-in-my-web-app/2039536#2039536

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for session- or request-scoped beans to work in Spring, something has to associate the current request and session with the current thread. Normally, this would be done by `DispatcherServlet`, but if you're not using that, then you need an alternative.

The alternative in this case is [`RequestContextListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextListener.html) or [`RequestContextFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/RequestContextFilter.html), either of which you can wire in to your `web.xml`, and both os which will allow you to use request- and session-scoped beans. Just make sure that you configure them in `web.xml` so that DWR requests pass through them.

Comment: If my web.xml has a spring DispatcherServlet AND a DwrServlet, then the dwr request would pass through the DwrServlet wouldn't it? Oh, and those classes are the "default" classes.. if I want to extend their functionality I'd have to inherit from them right? And if so where would my code go and where would I put the inherited class and how would I link to it? ... On second though I ought to make this a new question ...

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Session scoped bean is accessed by a global or a singleton. In that case you need to lower the scope of calling bean.

Comment: Obviously not the answer to this question, but it solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Or by creating a scoped proxy:
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

Comment: I think that will require teh RequestContextLisener and the bean have an interface.