# Configuring MockHttpServletRequest in unit controller test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking, spring-test

I am trying to attach a parameter to a session using `MockHttpServletRequest`, but only declare a attribute in my test I am getting the followin error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

I've tried do add `<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
   </listener>`, like saying to do in this link: [Getting a 'No thread-bound request found' error from spring in my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039522/getting-a-no-thread-bound-request-found-error-from-spring-in-my-web-app)

Test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = WebContextLoader.class, classes = { TestApplicationWebContext.class })
public class ClienteControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Resource
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired
private org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest request;

@Before
public void inicializacao() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void teste() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/administracao/cliente")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(forwardedUrl("administracao-cliente/index"));
}
```

}

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Configuring a listener in `web.xml` will have no effect on integration tests with the Spring MVC Test framework, since those tests run *outside the Servlet container*.

I obviously haven't seen the controller code you're trying to test, but if you can upgrade to Spring 3.2, I believe this should work out of the box thanks to the `ServletTestExecutionListener` that is registered by default. This works in conjunction with support for the new `@WebAppConfiguration` annotation introduced in Spring 3.2. See the examples in the [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server) for details.

If that doesn't work for you, please consider [creating a test case that reproduces the error](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework-issues#readme) and/or [opening a JIRA issue](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) describing your problem in greater detail.

Cheers,

Sam

Comment: I am using Spring 3.1, at the moment the project that I work can't updrage to Spring 3.2, is there any way to do this using 3.1 version? Thanks.