# How to get http session id in logout listener?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security, logout

My listener listen user log out.
I need to know session id at this listener.

```
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
         RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId();
    }
}
```

It generates

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

How to fix it in my concrete situation?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039522/getting-a-no-thread-bound-request-found-error-from-spring-in-my-web-app) on StackOverflow. Add the following to your `web.xml`:

```
<web-app>
  ...
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  ...
</web-app>
```