# @Async in a method will throws org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

Following is my method:

```
@Async
@Override
public void managerSmsBlackListExportTxt(SmsBlackImportInput input) {
    String blackMobile = input.getSmsBlackPhones();
    String regex = "\r\n";
    String[] blackMobiles = blackMobile.split(regex);

    Set<String> blackMobilesSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(blackMobiles));
    List<SystemPhoneFailedList> failedList = new ArrayList<>();    
    for (String userTel : blackMobilesSet) { 
        if (! this.checkTelephone(userTel.trim())){
            SystemPhoneFailedList systemPhoneFailedList = new SystemPhoneFailedList();
            ...
            failedList.add(systemPhoneFailedList);
            continue;
        }
        ...
    }

    systemPhoneFailedListBizMapper.insertSystemPhoneFailedListBatch(failedList); // the exception is in this line
}
```

when I debug it, I found the exception comes from(SqlSessionTemplate):

[image]

and the exception is:
`org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException`:

```
Error updating database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

[image]

If I delete `@Async`,this method will be OK and the data will insert into MySQL successfully.

Comment: Have you enabled asynchronous calls to your method using `@EnableAsync`?

Comment: yes,enabled asynchronous calls to my method,<task:annotation-driven executor="executor" />
<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10"/> , this Is my xml configure.

Comment: Please check @EnableAsync annotation added in this class..

Comment: Have you added the `RequestContextListener` class to your servlet context? Are you using XML or Java config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a 'No thread-bound request found' error from spring in my web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039522/getting-a-no-thread-bound-request-found-error-from-spring-in-my-web-app)

Comment: @Lucky yes,i have added the RequestContextListener in my web.xml like that,but it also dose not work. and i am using XML.

Comment: i think i don't need @EnableAsync annotation added in this class, because i am using XML <task:annotation-driven executor="executor" /> <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10"/>, and my php surely get the java response although when i debugging the method。

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21355974/1793718

Comment: @Lucky thank you，it maybe pointed the cause.